# how to change the permalink to a specific location?

Tags: posts, pages, slideshow

I have this slider on my front page. Right now when I click on an image it goes directly to the permalink and the post. How do I make all the slides go to one specific page?

this is the loop for the slider:

```
<ul class="tm_magzslider">
    <?php 
    $recent = new WP_Query( array(  "cat" => $tmcategory, 
                                    "posts_per_page" => $tm_totalpost, 
                                    "post_type" => "post", 
                                 ) 
                          ); 
    while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post(); 
    ?>

        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>        
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
        <img src="<?php $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(); $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,"img737", true); echo $image_url[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>">
        </a></li>       
        <?php } else { ?>       
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/nophoto515.png" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>">
        </a></li>
        <?php } ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

I changed the code to this but still it dosent work?:

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>        
        <li><a href="<?php get_permalink(22); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
        <img src="<?php $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(); $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,"img737", true); echo $image_url[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>">
        </a></li>       
        <?php } else { ?>       
        <li><a href="<?php get_permalink(22); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/nophoto515.png" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>">
        </a></li>
        <?php } ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: You should be doing the changes in a child theme and not your parent theme. You could use a slider which enables you to add custom url's.

Answer (score 0):

`echo get_permalink(123);` instead of `the_permalink()`, provided  you know the ID of the "specific page".

`the_permalink()` will always link to the current post in the Loop, and somewhat nonsensically does not take an ID parameter the way that `get_permalink()` does.

**Reference:** https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink

Comment: i tried changing it but still it dosent work =/

Comment: Make sure you change the ID-- first parameter-- and make sure you `echo` the return value of `get_permalink()`.

Comment: I tried this but it dosent work. what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo get_the_permalink($id)`(Your post $id)
Or `echo get_the_permalink()`